# EasyAdmin Adding Custom Web Assets

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack, easyadmin

I am trying to add google map search capability for my project and i found a very nice react code for this (https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) but i couldn't add this to my admin panel.
The problem is i couldn't add custom javascript file to easyadmin.
At documentation it says we can add custom web assest like below

```
- '/bundles/user/js/admin4.js'
- 'bundles/app/js/admin5.js'
```

But i couldn't understand which folder should i place my custom javascript file. In the easyadminbundle example there is a custom demo.css which was placed under `/src/Resources/public/stylesheets` folder; i tried something like that but it didn't work.

Then i tried to use webpack encore to add this custom javascript file but then i saw my webpack assets were not loaded in easyadmin.

So i am stuck, i hope you can help me to understand how can i add my custom javascript.

Answer (score 1):

## adding custom web assets in a specific page

according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#using-your-own-templates-to-display-the-edit-new-views) :

> Add the templates option (globally or only to some entities) to define the path of the Twig template used to render each part of the interface

```
# config/packages/easy_admin.yaml
easy_admin:
    design:
        # these custom templates are applied to all entities
        templates:
            edit: 'admin/custom_edit_form.html.twig'
    entities:
        Customer:
            # ...
            # these custom templates are only applied to this entity and
            # they override any global template defined in 'design.templates'
            templates:
                edit: 'admin/customer/edit.html.twig'
                new: 'admin/customizations/customer_new.html.twig'
```

Those files live in the `templates` folder.

then extend the default template of easyadmin:

```
{# templates/admin/new.html.twig #}
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/new.html.twig' %}

{% block head_custom_stylesheets %}
    {# ... customize the stylesheets with webpack-encore or rel element #}

{% block body_custom_javascript %}
    {# ... customize the javascripts with webpack-encore or script ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

There you can access everything as you used to do in the rest of your template (e.g. use global twig variable)

Comment: Actually i found a solution this problem months ago but forgot to post it here. This post reminded me this question. Let me check my solution and compare with your answer.